# Unexpected scrollbars appearing in mobile version of a website

Tags: html, css, mobile

1. Setup:

```
<!-- styles -->
<style>
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .square {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<!-- body -->
<body>
  <div class="square"></div>
</body>
```

2. Add the following CSS properties to `.square`:

```css
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
top: 0;
```

3. Observe the page in the browser:

If you view it from the desktop view, it works as expected (the page is empty, no scrollbars appearing and no scrolling can be done).

Open DevTools, then click "Toggle devices toolbar" (`ctrl + shift + m`). Now, try scrolling right. You will see the red square. You can also scroll down for some reason.

[screenshot (notice the overflow:hidden applied to body)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZche.png) - on this screenshot page is already scrolled to the right.

Also, if you change `left: 100%` to `right: 100%` it works as expected. Same works for `transition: translateX()`.

[deployed version](https://aquamarine-cayla-9.tiiny.site/)

The same behavior was observed on Edge (desktop, with device toolbar on), Samsung Internet and Chrome (mobile). I also checked this via BrowserStack: the issue persisted on Chrome v90, 101 and 105.

Chrome desktop version: 120.0.6099.130 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)

Chrome mobile version: 120.0.6099.144 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with Chrome’s inspector. There’s nothing wrong with your code, which works fine everywhere except in Chrome’s inspector.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;    
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But I noticed it really works that way (overflow is not hidden) on a real mobile Chrome browser.